# cplex constraint function of a variable

Tags: c++, linear-programming, cplex

I have an *optimization variable* x and a constant y.

I want to express a constraint

```
f(x) <= y.
```

I tried doing

```
 27: IloRange rng = (f(cplex->getValue(x)) <= y);
 28: model.add(rng);
```

But I get the error

```
cplex.cpp:27: error: conversion from 'bool' to non-scalar type 'IloRange' requested
```

Can someone help me write a constraint of this form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, strict inequality is not possible with linear programming.  You can however express

```
f(x) <= y
```

cplex->getValue(x) is a double so f(x) <= y is a boolean.  At any rate, cplex->getValue() is only available after you have a solution so it should never be part of your model, unless you are solving it iteratively.  To get a IloRange, you need to rewrite f(x) to accept an IloNumVar as it's parameter and to return an IloExpr.  For example, if you have something like

```
double f(double x) {return 2*x;}
```

You need a version

```
IloExpr f(IloNumVarx) {return 2*x;}
```

Then you can write

```
IloRange rng = (f(x) <= y);
```

If you are using cplex (or any linear programming solver), f(x) can only be a linear function or convex quadratic function.

Comment: First, you are my hero: it was failing because getValue cannot be a part of the model, and re-writing f(x) as a "cplex" version is the way to go, thanks! I think that is a pain, because f is nontrivial, and now I have to rewrite it using all of their notation, but O well. As far as linearity is concerned, CPLEX (atleast as of 12.4) now supports MILP programming, with integer and binary constraints. The constraint may have to be integer linear or integer quadratic, but I don't think it has to be convex because it may not even be continuous if x is binary or integer constrained.

Comment: You mentioned "unless I solve it iteratively". Is there a way I can solve it iteratively and not have to rewrite f? Perhaps a pointer to using getValue() in a model that is solved iteratively?

Comment: @Tommy You would solve a problem iteratively if you wanted to use the results of an optimization to make a different solution.  It would not help in your case.  To avoid multiple version of the code, you can use C++ templates.